# MYSQL Union over Multiple Given Values

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to word my question so I'll just state what I'm trying to do.  Say I have one query that gives me customer ID's like so:

```
SELECT C.cid
FROM Customer Cust;
```

I would then like to have (maybe?) a nested query where I can reference those customer ID's so that I can union over every pair of customers (each pair contains customer a and customer b where a != b).  So I am trying to use the above results in the query like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P1.pid
FROM Purchase P1
WHERE P1.cid = Cust.id
UNION
SELECT P2.pid
FROM Purchase P2
WHERE P2.cid != Cust.id
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Do you think you could maybe give us sample data and desired result set(s)?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query